# State not immediately saved with socket.io

Tags: node.js, typescript, sockets, react-hooks, socket.io

As you can see in my problem below, I receive a message with the action stop. There I update 3 state variables. My problem is with the `setTotalScore`. `totalScore` is 0 in the beginning, and when I receive the message, I update it to be the same as the `user.score`. But, if I receive the message again, it is 0 again, even though it shouldn't be. I have read everywhere that it is a problem with how `useState` updates. I don't really know how to work around that. Here is the code:

```js
socket.on(`${WsTopic.GAME}/${WsAction.STOP}`, (payload) => {
  const user = payload.find((entry: any) => entry.username == name)
  if (user) {
    console.log("USER: ", user," USER.SCORE: ", user.score);
    console.log("SCORE: ", totalScore);

    const addedScore = user.score - totalScore;

    setTotalScore(user.score);
    setAddedScore(addedScore);
    setShowAnswer(true);
  }
})
```

```js
const [totalScore, setTotalScore] = useState<number>(0);
```

The `totalScore` should always be updated and equal to the `user.score`. You can look at it like the `totalScore` is the prevScore of the `user.score`.

Comment: Show full component please, but probably stale closure

Answer (score 0):

This is a Javascript closure issue, the socket closes over the `totalScore` state value from the render cycle where the socket event handler is instantiated and handed off to the socket.

You can use a `useEffect` with proper dependencies to re-enclose variables:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const stopHandler = (payload) => {
    const user = payload.find((entry: any) => entry.username == name);
    if (user) {
      console.log("USER: ", user," USER.SCORE: ", user.score);
      console.log("SCORE: ", totalScore);

      const addedScore = user.score - totalScore;

      setTotalScore(user.score);
      setAddedScore(addedScore);
      setShowAnswer(true);
    }
  };

  socket.on(`${WsTopic.GAME}/${WsAction.STOP}`, stopHandler);

  return () => {
    socket.off(`${WsTopic.GAME}/${WsAction.STOP}`, stopHandler);
  };
}, [totalScore]);
```

You could also use a React ref to cache the current `totalScore` state value and reference this in the handler:

```js
const [totalScore, setTotalScore] = useState<number>(0);
const totalScoreRef = React.useRef(totalScore);

React.useEffect(() => {
  totalScoreRef.current = totalScore;
}, [totalScore]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const stopHandler = (payload) => {
    const user = payload.find((entry: any) => entry.username == name);
    if (user) {
      console.log("USER: ", user," USER.SCORE: ", user.score);
      console.log("SCORE: ", totalScoreRef.current);

      const addedScore = user.score - totalScoreRef.current;

      setTotalScore(user.score);
      setAddedScore(addedScore);
      setShowAnswer(true);
    }
  };

  socket.on(`${WsTopic.GAME}/${WsAction.STOP}`, stopHandler);

  return () => {
    socket.off(`${WsTopic.GAME}/${WsAction.STOP}`, stopHandler);
  };
}, []);
```